# R automatically reference changing row numbers in my code comments

Tags: r, comments

In my R code, I would like to reference specific lines of code in the comments, even though they keep changing. Is there a way to automatically reference changing row numbers in my code comments?

```
1 #See code in row 2
2 df <- df$example
…
```

```
1 #See code in row 3
2 #There's a new line
3 df <- df$example
…
```

```
1 #See code in row 4
2 #There's a new line
3 #There's a new line
4 df <- df$example
…
```

Comment: Might be of interest: https://opensourcelibs.com/lib/strcode